# Can I run a Dart program in production mode with the Editor?

Tags: dart

I'd like to run my Dart program in production mode instead of checked mode. I am using the Dart Editor. Can I control the runtime mode?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you can! Find the "Run in checked mode" checkbox inside "Manage Launches". Unchecking this will run your Dart program in production mode.

Remember, in production mode, the static type annotations are ignored.

Comment: Doesn't un-checking the debugger speed things up a bit too?  It feels like it does to me, but I don't have any data to prove it.

Comment: John, Based on some of my tests with Stopwatch on various sorting algorithms, both Debugger and Checked Mode add overhead. While I don't have concrete numbers, I'm looking at a two to three factor increase in execution time with either or both options enabled.